# Buffer Selected Line Segments Using ArcGIS 10 or Python

Tags: arcgis-10.0, python, buffer

I haven't  quite found a solution for buffering selected line segments of a road network without extporting the selected line segments to a new file and then buffering.  I want to avoid creating a bunch of new datasets for this task.  Either environment will do (ArcGIS application or Python).  Any suggestions?

Comment: If you run the Buffer geoprocessing tool from ArcMap on the layer with the selection, does it give the desired results? Most geoprocessing tools operate on the selected set by default, if present.

Comment: Excellent, It worked. Never knew that such functionality was available. Thanks for chiming in.

Comment: @dchaboya, on a side note, it would be great if you marked "accept" in your previously asked questions when you get an answer that works for you...

Comment: Doh! I'm still trying to get a hang of this site.  Thanks for the info.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Run the Buffer geoprocessing tool from ArcMap on the layer with the selection. Most geoprocessing tools operate on the selected set by default, if present.